# Setting up and solving this second order nonlinear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, electromagnetism

## Background

I'm trying to model a system where there are two magnets oriented such that they have attraction forces toward each other.  One magnet is in a fixed position and the other magnet, $M$, is in free space and starts at the origin which is some distance away from the fixed magnet.

As $M$ approaches the fixed magnet due to the attraction force, the force will increase with the square of the distance from the origin.

$$F = C{y^2}$$

I want to model this part of the system where $M$ begins moving toward the fixed magnet and can ignore what happens when they collide.

## The problem

I figure this is a second order non-linear differential equation.

$$my'' = C{y^2}$$

Or

$$y'' = Cy^{2}$$

For some coefficient $C$.

> How do I go about solving this equation?

I would expect $y(t)$ grow exponentially and I haven't been able to find a solution that does this.

Initial position (with respect to origin) is zero.  Initial velocity is zero.

$$y(0) = 0$$
$$ y'(0) = 0$$

Comment: I am afraid you will have to invert a function containing an integral to get the solution and its inverse may not expressible in terms of elementary functions. So I presume you should solve it numerically.

Comment: Could you tell what are the conditions ?

Comment: If you use **R**, you could be interested by  https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/elliptic/vignettes/ellipticpaper.pdf

Comment: Updated with conditions

Answer (score 1):

Using chain rule, you can rewrite the equation:

$$\frac{d^2 y}{dt^2} = C y^2 \\
\dot{y}\frac{d\dot{y}}{dy} = Cy^2 \\
$$

Integrating, you get:

$$\frac{\dot{y}^2}{2}=\frac{C}{3}y^3+D \\
\frac{dy}{dt} = \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}Cy^3 + E}$$

As far as I know, there is no simplification for the last integral. You will have to resort to numerical calculations.

Comment: Let's assume E is 0.  Then you can integrate and get $y =Cy^{5/2}$ for some arbitrary C.  This is not a solution that makes sense as y is just constant.

Comment: @Conor What about the constant of integration ? And what about time variable $t$ ??

Answer (score 0):

There is an analytical solution to the equation $$y''=C\, y^2$$ It is given as
$$y=\sqrt[3]{\frac 6 C}\,\wp \left(\sqrt[3]{\frac C6}
   \left(x+c_1\right);0,c_2\right)$$ where appears  the Weierstrass elliptic function ( have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass%27s_elliptic_functions) and [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/WeierstrassP/introductions/Weierstrass/ShowAll.html)).

Comment: If I understand correctly, the Weierstrass function works in the complex plane.  Is it practical to use this to analyze y (position) as a function of time?